# How do generate RSS feed from private Google Site

Tags: rss, google-sites

We have a private google site on google apps but want to be able to generate an rss feed so people within our domain can add the feed to different readers (including google reader) how can we generate this feed?

Answer (score 0):

Write a web service that will have the credentials to fetch data from the private Google Site.
Have it fetch the feed you need and republish it.
Check the Google Sites API documentation for details.
You can put the URL of the web service on the site where your users can find it.
Note that you will need access to a web server and some server programming skills to do this.